# Anime about fighting sentient crystal beings and fusing with them

Tags: story-identification, anime

Sorry if the info is bad, i have bad spelling and bad memory, I will give out my best to tell about the anime.

The anime starts of with a male character that's in middle school/high school, (if I remember correctly, the main character was walking down some stairs with his friends)

The main character saw a sentient crystal beast (and tried to fight it, I think?), and then a huge dome creates out of thin air to make any being cant go inside or outside

"Input story plot here"

And then the main character got invited or joined to a crew (about fighting sentient crystal beings with sentient crystal beings)

The main character is now in a area (that is like a half donut with 3 or 5 floors)

The main character gained a special device that can make the character and the crystal fused together (The crystal turned into armor + weapon(s) and the user can use it.

(btw, the tamed crystals can have emotions)

Sorry if the info is bad, im just telling about the first arc.

The info below is what i remembered after some rest and memory struggle to find

Just So you know, there are devices that every member of the HQ have, that are phone sized that you can communicate with the headquarters captain, or a specific or a group of members and is the core item to have the capability of fusing the human and the crystal together

the Mission: the missions are for defending humanity from those crystal beasts, and have a choice to either defeat and tame it for future uses or defeat and kill it permanently (Destroy it)

Villains: the villains are evil dudes, and in later parts of the series they made a machine that can force fusion with the crystal and humans, that is highly unstable of use after a specified amount of time

Fusion: what i mean't by fusion is that the user gains armor and a weapon of use, and there are phases between the bonds of the crystal and the human.

Phase 1: armor and weapon(s).

Phase 2: the capability of becoming the beast instead of just armor and weapon(s).

there are more phases, but this is all i can remember.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed a lot of the information you updated with?

Comment: He's found his answer, and evidently believes his work here is done. I've rolled back the edit because, in context, it seemed rather like vandalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for *[Fafner in the Azure: Dead Aggressor](http://alvis.towerofmist.net/index.php?title=Fafner_in_the_Azure:_Dead_Aggressor)*. It has teenagers fighting sentient crystal beasts. The [Welle Shield](http://alvis.towerofmist.net/index.php?title=Welle_Shield) resembles a dome. The military uses the crystals to create weapons to fight the monsters.

> Terrorized by a hostile alien race's mental warfare, humans hear only this question just before their lives-essentially their minds-are assimilated by the violent invaders. Kazuki and his classmates lay everything on the line to pilot their heavily-guarded island's secret weapons: towering mechs for which only they are genetically qualified to control. With most of Earth destroyed, humanity's survival relies on these youths' selfless determination to protect the only home they know. But when each battle pushes the pilots to the brink of assimilation, who will protect them?

### Trailer

Found with a search for `anime fight crystal monsters`

Comment: There is a very in-depth review at https://myanimelist.net/reviews.php?id=305355